# Trouble using conditional ng-class in Angular JS?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, anchor, ng-class

I have the following anchor tag:

```
<a href="#/home" ng-class="{ active: navCtrl.checkCurrent('home')" ng-click="navCtrl.setLink('home')" class="navigation-anchor">Home</a>
```

I have confirmed by manually adding `active` to the `class` attribute of this anchor that my class produces the intended result. I have also confirmed that `nav.Ctrl.checkCurrent('home')` evaluates to `true` when I've clicked this link.

However, that being said...this directive fails to produce the results I'm looking for.

The intended function is that when the function is true, the `active` class will be applied to my anchor tag.

Since I have checked that the class works, and the function produces the correct boolean operator, I must have the syntax for ng-class incorrect. However, I recently completed a tutorial on Code School dealing with Angular JS and they use the following syntax...

```
ng-class="{ active: tab.isSet(1) }"
```

...in an anchor tag. When the function `tab.isSet(1)` evaluates to true the class is applied to the element.

Why is my equal syntax not producing the same result?

Comment: Suggest you update the post with any error messages received in the console...

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you are missing the  closing "}" ?

```
<a href="#/home" ng-class="{ active: navCtrl.checkCurrent('home') }" ng-click="navCtrl.setLink('home')" class="navigation-anchor">Home</a>
```

Comment: This was an absolutely stupid mistake. I'm going to leave the question here and give you the accepted answer because you deserve it, but the moderators may think otherwise.

Comment: Thanks, I would have posted it as a comment, but I have not enough points yet.